# Django variable isnt recognized by javascript

Tags: javascript, django, json

I serialized an object of mine using the built in method with django and then passed it into my template. When I put {{goals}} in the html, the data shows perfectly. However, when I try to access it through a js script, it doesnt work. Why is this? I alerted it and it keeps coming as undefined.

```
#Python Views
def characterscreen(request):
    goals = serializers.serialize("json", Goal.objects.filter(userprofile=userprof)) 
    #goals = Goal.objects.filter(userprofile=userprof).values()
    return render_to_response('levelup/characterscreen.html', {'goals': goals}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

## Python Model

```
class Goal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    type = models.CharField(max_length = 5)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

## JS File

```
    $("body").onload =  load_goals();


function load_goals (){
     alert(goals);}
```

## HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'levelup/style.css' %}" />
        {% block header %}{% endblock%}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="headercontainer">
            <div id="header">

            </div>
        </div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}   <script type="text/Javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>  <script type="text/Javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">goals = "{{ goals|safe }}"</script>
        <script type="text/Javascript" src="{% static 'levelup/script.js' %}"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried removing the quotes and now the variable is just alerting a [object Object],[object Object] when I do alert(goals)

Comment: Since it is in a javascript file, it no longer has context of `{{goals}}` . move this code to your template instead.

Comment: You still have in your javascript:  alert({{goals}});.  Remove the {{}} from the javascript:  alert(goals);

Comment: Also, do you have a `__str__` or `__unicode__` method defined for your goals model?  Once you define such a method, then `[object Object]` will be replaced by that method's output.

Comment: I had alert(goals) in, I just didnt edit the above js script but I did now to reflect everything.

Answer (score 5):

That's because external .js files aren't processed like html files are. This only works with inline scripts. So you should put this in your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    goals = "{{ goals }}"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" />
```

Then you can use the goal variable in script.js.

EDIT:
JSON always uses double quotes, so you'll have to put single quotes around it. Additionally, althrough a JSON string actually represents a real Javascript object when used without quotes, it's best to parse the JSON before you use it. As you seem to be using jQUery, use:

```
goals = $.parseJSON('{{ goals|safe }}')
```

Comment: Thanks alot! It outputted which is great, but unfortunately with "&quot" marks around each key and value in the json object (since I serialized the variable as JSON in my views.py.) Would you happen to know why this is or how to fix it?

Comment: By default, every variable that isn't an instance of Django's `SafeString` `SafeUnicode` or `SafeBytes` classes will be auto-escaped. You can use `{% autoescape off %}` and `{% endautoescape %}` to prevent a block from being auto-escaped, but for single variables you'll want to use the `safe` filter, that will just mark a single variable as being safe: `{{ goals|safe }}`.

Comment: I tried that and the alert returned [object HTMLUListElement]. tHen I tried accessing goals.pk since that is one of the keys in the JSON, but the alert returned undefined. So is the javascript variable "goals" a JSON object after setting it to "{{ goals|safe }}" in the script tag in the html file? Im confused as to why when I try accessing a field of the goals variable it returns undefined.

Comment: Maybe you need to loose the quotes around `{{ goals|safe }}`. Can you post whats in the source code of your html page?

Comment: @user1987920 Actually meant: what do you see when you go to 'View page source' in your browser, or what is the output of `{{ goals|safe }}`. Anyway, I updated my answer with what I think should work, though my JSON seems to be a bit rusty at the moment.